# How do I loop through this array using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How would I output this data using Jquery.each() to loop over the following array using Jquery?

```
var data = [
{
value: 36,
color:"#89228f",
legend:"My title" 
},
{
value: 12,
color:"#89288f",
legend:"This title" 
}
]
```

I would like to output the results like this

```
  <li><div class="colorblock" style="background-color:#89288f"></div> <div class="legend">This title</div></li>


  <li><div class="colorblock" style="background-color:#89228f"></div> <div class="legend">My  title</div></li>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use jQuery and not PHP? Why are you doing this on the client side?

Comment: Need to use jquery because the result needs to be displayed in realtime based on user actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var string = $.map(data, function(data, index){
    return '<li><div class="colorblock" style="background-color:#' + data.color + '"></div> <div class="legend">' + data.title +'</div></li>'
}).join('');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qGjBV/)

Answer (score 1):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZrNM/)

```
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    $("#id_of_your_ul").append('<li><div class="colorblock" style="background-color:'+ val.color +'"></div> <div class="legend">'+ val.legend +'</div></li>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation gives a good explanation of how to use .each
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  // create div element with data
  // append the new div to the DOM
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ is a great place to look for an answer to your question. Your key issue will be decide whether to use 1 or 2 selectors. 2 might be simpler to get you going here - the first to pick all divs with class legend

```
 $('div.legend').each(data,function(i,v){
         $(this).text=v.legend;
 });
```

You may want to check that data has more or equal elements to the number picked in the selector.

You'd do something similar with the $('div.colorblock').each() using the .attr('style',value)

You could use 1 selector and look at the div child elements of the

elements. The first using the .attr('style',value) and the second looking at text. I think right now you may just want to get it working and then optimise selector usage depending on your page layout.